# MS Access error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" on text field compared with text criterion

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access I have a query that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [stored_query] WHERE [derived_column] = "123456"
```

`derived_column` is generated in `stored_query` via

```sql
SELECT [other_columns],
       Replace(Replace([some_table].[some_short_text_column], "search1", "replacement1"),
               "search2", "replacement2") AS derived_column,
       [more_columns]
FROM (some_table_join_action)
```

`[some_table].[some_short_text_column]` is a 255-character text field in the database.  So, a `short text` field is replaced with a string, which is replaced with a string.  Some values generated via `stored_query` look like:

- Administration
- Salaries
- Temp Employee Wage

and so on, so definitely text.  To be extra certain, through some code action I have confirmed that `derived_column` is a string, namely `DataTypeEnum.dbText`.  However, when I run that first query I get the following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

My interpretation of this error is that I shouldn't be using a string in the `WHERE` clause, even though the derived column should be a string.  For good measure I tried removing the square braces, removing the quotes, replacing the criterion with a #-formatted date, and even another call to `Replace()` so that my query looked more like

```sql
SELECT * FROM [stored_query] WHERE [derived_column] = Replace("123456", "garbage_in", "garbage_out")
```

but I still get the type mismatch error.

If I use the drop-down filters on the one column in the Datasheet View of the stored query, the datasheet clears.  The filter options are then gone and "Clear filter from [column]" is grayed out.

**Am I missing something, or is this just another quirk of Access?**

---

To flesh out the stored query, this is what it looks like (with a bit of obfuscation to maintain client confidentiality):

```sql
SELECT Receipt.receipt_num,
    Expense.report_id,
    Receipt.schedule_num,
    Expense.assoc_id,
    Income.tgri_num,
    Expense.project_type,
    Expense.fiscal_year,
    Expense.expense_date,
    Expense.amount,
    Expense.description,
    Income_Expense.expense,
    Income_Expense.expense_date,
    Income_Expense.notes,
    Income.project_num,
    Income.project_type,
    Income.program_area,
    tgri_num.voucher_desc,
    Format([start_date],"mmm-yy") AS min_date,
    Format([end_date],"mmm-yy") AS max_date,
    tgri_num.ID_tgri_num,
    Receipt.rep_period,
    Replace(Replace([expense_categories].[project_type],
        "Temp Employee Wage","Salaries"),
        "Salaries",
        "Salary and Benefits") AS project_desc,
    Income_Expense.notes
FROM
(
    (
        Income INNER JOIN tgri_num ON (tgri_num.fiscal_year = Income.fiscal_year)
        AND (Income.tps = tgri_num.tps) AND (Income.tgri_num = tgri_num.tgri_num)
    )
    INNER JOIN expense_categories ON Income.project_type =
                                            expense_categories.expense_cat_id
)
INNER JOIN
(
    (
        Receipt INNER JOIN Expense ON Receipt.report_id = Expense.report_id
    )
    INNER JOIN Income_Expense ON Expense.expense_id = Income_Expense.expense_id
) ON Income.income_id = Income_Expense.income_id;
```

Comment: It all works for me. The Replace query works? Where do the replace inputs come from? Perhaps edit question to show representative data.

Comment: Yeah, the `Replace()` query works, while querying its results is what generates the error.  (Querying the results of query results is used a lot in this project.)  I've added more details to the question, but in any case `some_short_text_column` exists in the database while the rest of the parameters of `Replace()` are strings hardcoded into the stored query.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still cannot replicate issue.

Comment: My guess now is the query is simply processing far too much data, maybe runs out of memory, causes a bunch of errors, and the underlying issue is not the one that bubbled up through the error reporting.  Perhaps the Replace() command fails and is returning a non-string.